# In Scala, how do you combine the sequence of elements of the same List?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

How do I transform this list:

```
List("a", "b", "c", "d")
```

into a list with the following elements

```
List(List("a"), List("a", "b"), List("a", "b", "c"), List("a", "b", "c", "d"))
```

My requirement is to build a list of relative directory paths from a list containing directory names, where `a` is the root directory and `b` is a leaf of `a` i.e. `a/b`

Example:

```
"fruit", "tropical", "mango"
```

transforms to:

```
"fruit", "fruit/tropical", "fruit/tropical/mango"
```

Edit: I can do this iteratively, but I'm looking for a **functional** solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `inits` to achieve similar thing you are looking for:

```
val xs = List("a", "b", "c", "d")
val ys = xs.inits.toList.reverse.drop(1)
```

Explanation:

`xs.inits.toList` will give you this result:

```
List(List(a, b, c, d), List(a, b, c), List(a, b), List(a), List())
```

Now you can reverse it and drop the first element and get this:

```
List(List(a), List(a, b), List(a, b, c), List(a, b, c, d))
```

Then, just make a `String` of results you got:

```
ys.map(_.mkString("/")) // results in List(a, a/b, a/b/c, a/b/c/d)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should probably use `inits` (I would avoid relying on the order of the returned elements, although it is documented that the last element is the empty one):

```
val basket = List("fruit", "tropical", "mango")
basket.inits.toList filterNot (_.isEmpty) sortBy (_.length) map (_ mkString "/")
```

However, if you want an approach that doesn't use that library function, you could roll your own recursive function:

```
def paths(elems: List[String]): List[List[String]] = {
  elems match { 
    case Nil     => Nil
    case e :: es => List(e) :: (paths(es) map (e :: _))
  }
}
paths(basket) map (_ mkString "/")
```

This isn't tail-recursive, so it will blow the stack if your path is *many* elements deep.  You could make it tail-recursive using an accumulating parameter (actually, two accumulating parameters is the best I can do):

```
@annotation.tailrec
final def paths(elems: List[String], path: List[String], acc: List[List[String]]): List[List[String]] = {
  elems match {
    case Nil     => acc
    case e :: es => paths(es, path :+ e, acc :+ (path :+ e))
  }
}
paths(basket, Nil, Nil) map (_ mkString "/")
```

This solution uses the `:+` operator (append element) on `List` a lot though, so it's not optimal with respect to time complexity.  I'll leave fixing that as an exercise for the reader (hint: you would probably want to store the accumulating parameters in reverse order).